# Gerando um arquivo que é saída de um comando apenas se uma condição for satisfeita

Tags: shell-script, linha-de-comando

Seja o comando:

```
top -o %MEM -b > file.txt
```

Gostaria que em file.txt só estivem os valores que estivem entre dois períodos de tempo, como por exemplo:

entre 07 de Abril de 2017 07h e 07 de Abril de 2017 12h. É possível? Desta forma, eu teria um arquivo apenas com as entradas que me interessam.

Gostaria de guardar num arquivo apenas as entradas que estiverem entre 07 de Abril de 2017 07h e 07 de Abril de 2017 12h!!!

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta. A condição é relacionada a algum valor emitido pelo `top`?

Comment: Nao! gostaria de guardar num arquivo apenas as entradas que estão entre 07 de Abril de 2017 07h e 07 de Abril de 2017 12h!!!

Comment: De onde você pega essa informação? Você quer rodar o script apenas nesses horários segundo o clock do computador?

Comment: seria um horario que eu informasse a ele. Poderia usar Unix time para facilitar. Poque top -o %MEM -b > file.txt gera muita coisa que não me interessa. Quero só a informação entre datas que eu informe!

Comment: É possível fazer isso?

Comment: Você quer fazer um agendamento, que não tem nada a ver com parâmetros de função. Achei essa fonte aqui em inglês que pode te ajudar: https://www.howtogeek.com/101288/how-to-schedule-tasks-on-linux-an-introduction-to-crontab-files/

Comment: nao! top -o %MEM -b > file.txt irá gerar um arquivo com o uso de memoria e CPU com inúmeros dias e horarios que nao me interessam! eu queria fatiar o arquivo antes de ser gerado para guardar apenas o intervalo acima!

Comment: Então a saída do `top` tem alguma informação relevante de data? Se tiver, por preguiça eu usaria um `grep ` para selecionar

Comment: Não entendi!Poderia dar exemplo?

Comment: O problema é que ele demora muito para gerar o arquivo. gostaria de dizer ao comando top que só guarde no arquivo entre os periodos que informei

Comment: `cat /var/log/apache.log /var/log/anaconda.log | grep jeff` só vai pegar as linhas que tenham `jeff`. Leia sobre `grep` e pipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não ficou completamente claro o que pretendes...

Obviamente não conseguimos analisar a memória usada no passado. 
Comecemos por guardar o uso de memória
(com `top`) desde a atualidade até daqui a 2horas. Para tal sugeria
que:

- definíssemos um intervalo de amostragem (exemplo 30 segundos)
- definíssemos um número de amostras (120 * 60s /30s = 240)

```
top -o '%MEM' -d 30 -n 240 -b > file.txt
... analisar_e_limpar file.txt > resumo.txt
```

(`top` tem muitas opções que permitem esconder, acrescentar campos, etc).

Se pretendermos começar o registo algures no futuro, podemos usar a cron-tab ou usar o comando "esperar ..." : `sleep ...; top ...`

Comment: como seria com crontab? eu queria monitorar  e guardar, na proxima segunda, terça e quarta-feira de 07h às 15h

Comment: @EdS, procura os detalhes em `man 5 crontab` mas seria algo como editar a cron tab (`crontab -e`) e adiionar-lhe uma linha como `0 7 * * mon,tue,wen /home/EdS/script`  (não testado) em que escolhias a amostragem e quantidade pretendidas

Comment: Qual a diferença entre fazer > file.txt e >>file.txt ??

Comment: Usando `> file.txt ` voce vai sobrescrever o que tiver no arquivo e colocar o novo conteudo, usando `>> file.txt` voce vai concatenar o conteúdo novo com o que já está no arquivo

Answer (score 3):

Imagino eu que o grep não vá resolver nesse caso, porém você pode com shell script pegar linha por linha do conteúdo do top, daí vai de voce criar uma lógica para pegar a hora e comparar por exemplo: 
suponhamos que a linha vem assim: drwxrwxrwx victor:victor hh:mm:ss nomeArquivo
isso é um exemplo apenas você poderia pegar essa linha e quebrar nos espaços, depois pegar o 3 elemento que seria hh:mm:ss e dai quebrar no ':' dai voce teria separado hora, minuto e segundo, depois disso voce poderia comparar a hora é igual ou maior que 07? ou a hora é menor ou igual a 11? e dai colocar essa linha no arquivo final, a lógica eu tenho certeza que funciona, porém estou enferrujado em shell script e não vou poder te fornecer o código :/